# How do I get the application data path in Windows using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, application-data

I looked all over the internet and there doesn't seem to be a decent solution that I could find. I want to be able to programmatically in C++ obtain the path "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data" that explorer can translate into a real path.

Can I do this without relying on third-party code?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use [`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) with [`CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28VS.85%29.aspx#CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA) as the CSIDL.

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, NULL, 0, szPath)))
{
    //....
}
```

Comment: Nice, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA IS the CSIDL I'm looking for.

Comment: There is also the newer, and not necessarily spiffier, SHGetKnownFolderPath.  Available on Vista or later.

Comment: I also want to add that there's CSIDL_APPDATA which is the user-specific version of this. (COMMON_APPDATA is shared across all users)

Answer (score 22):

Just to suppliment interjay's answer

1. I had to include `shlobj.h` to use `SHGetFolderPath`.
2. Often you may need to read a file from appdata,
   to do this you need to use the `pathAppend` function (`shlwapi.h` is needed for this).

```cpp
#include <shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"shlwapi.lib")
#include "shlobj.h"

TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
// Get path for each computer, non-user specific and non-roaming data.
if ( SUCCEEDED( SHGetFolderPath( NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, NULL, 0, szPath ) ) )
{
    // Append product-specific path
    PathAppend( szPath, _T("\\My Company\\My Product\\1.0\\") );
}
```

See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310294) for more details.

Comment: +1 and a note: to use _T("...") you have to `#include <tchar.h>`

Comment: You should be using the `TEXT()` macro instead of the `_T()` macro (or, stop using `TCHAR` altogether - unless you really need to support Win9x/ME).  `TEXT()` is used by the Win32 API, `_T()` is used by the C runtime library.

Answer (score -4):

you can also read the value from the registry

path = **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders**

key = **Common AppData**

Comment: Undocumented and subject to change; avoid it. There's the API, use it.

Comment: Note that 'Subject to change' status is subject to change for all things in Win32 world.

Comment: The API is not always available.  Certain very early versions of Windows not running desktops do not have the SHGetFolderPath API.  But, if you do not have to support Windows XP or Windows 2000, you can rely on SHGetFolderPath's availability.  Yes, obscure, perhaps an edge case, but enough people have run into this to influence at least one boost library to use this approach.