# Win32 Application Settings

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, settings

How can I store settings that can later be loaded into my application?

For instance, I have an edit control that the user can change the font, font color, and background color of. When the user changes these, I would like to save them so that when the user opens the application again the fonts and colors will be the same as they left them.

I had thought about writing to the windows registry, but not only am I confused as to how to save fonts there, (or even if you could do such a thing), but I also have a portable version that can be run off of a flash-drive. Is there any way to save these settings to a file that is in the same directory as the executable? If so, how would I go about saving and loading these?

If there isn't a way to accomplish this using a settings file, how could I use the windows registry to do it?

Comment: If you can use boost libraries, you should review [`boost::property_tree`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/property_tree.html#boost_propertytree.intro) library. I have never used this, but seems to be what you are after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way IMO is to store it in ini files, for example, one file : app.ini

```
[AppSettings]
fntBackground=255 255 0
fntFace=Tahome

[LoadDialog]
...
```

it is quite easy to write it yourself, you can also find ready classes on codeproject, I took a fast search and found this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5401/CIni

looks promising

Comment: Yes, looks very promising. Now, this maybe a whole other question but lets say the .ini file is beside my executable, which is in `C:\Program Files\MyProgram`, how would I get access to write to it? And what if the user can't give the application administration privileges? I would like to still be able to run my program but I guess just not save the settings when they are changed.

Comment: I can do without that question being answered if you don't have one, but one thing I really want to know is: Can instead of writing a `int`, `bool`, or `char` to the INI file, can I write a `LOGFONT` structure to it? If not I would have to save every member of the `LOGFONT` structure to a different key and somehow deal with converting the `long`s and `BYTE`s to integers.

Comment: store settings in application data folder, to get its path look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899013/how-do-i-get-the-application-data-path-in-windows-using-c.

Comment: LOGFONT - it would be safier to store each field separately, but this CIni class provides CIni::WriteDataBlock(..) method that allows you to store/load binary data, you would only have to specify pointer to your LOGFONT object as lpData parameter. But in my opinion thats unsafe.

Comment: Great stuff, thank you. How would I go about making sure `(APPDATADIR)//MyCompany//MyProgram//1.0//Settings.ini` is created if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: I looked at `CreateFile()` but I don't know if it creates the directory, or what parameters to use just to create the blank file so that my `CIni` object can use it.

Answer (score 2):

If your application is allowed to write to the folder, then you can use an .ini file as many Windows application do. You can read and write to the file with `GetPrivateProfile/WritePrivateProfile` APIs, e.g [`GetPrivateProfileInt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If you are using some framework, it is possible that it also provides friendlier version of the API (e.g. MFC provides [`CWinApp::GetProfileInt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z024c0d3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and others).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to read config info in Windows is by using [GetPrivateProfileString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/WritePrivateProfileString functions as Zdeslav Vojkovic said.

But then you see this: *Note  This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit Windows-based applications. Applications should store initialization information in the registry.* Which is obsolete nowadays either and often is forbidden. Recommendations (but often just simple fashion) require you to use [XML files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163383.aspx) for this. Then you can use whatever method you like - DOM, SAX, [XMLLite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms752838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: SOM/SAX... - why complicate simple things ?