# Deploying text files in c++

Tags: c++

I have encountered a problem when deploying a game I made in C++. I will try and be as specific as possible.I did research this thoroughly on Google and I also asked a former programming teacher and he recommended I post to this site. I created a game in C++ and inside the source folder I had added 3 text files named: "SavedGame1.txt" "SavedGame2.txt" and "SavedGame3.txt". I built a save function that when triggered, it writes the information such as player name, class, hitpoints, mana, etc to the text file so it can be read back later in my continue function. When I run it in Visual Studio (I am using Visual Studio 2010 by the way), it will write to the text file like desired and read back from the text file. After I deploy the game, it will read from the text files if they have data in them before I deploy the game, but the problem is after deployment, it will not write to the text files. This makes my save game function worthless. I found a way around this by creating a directory upon running my deployed game and then creating the save game text files in the directory, but then I face the issue of having to run the game in Admin mode or else it will not write to the text files. Can anyone tell me what I can do to get it to write to the text files so that the user does not have to be in Admin mode to use the save function.

Comment: Usually you would have an installer to create whatever directory structure you need for the game to function.

Comment: You haven't said what kind of error it produces, but it sounds like a permission problem. Why put those files in the bundle at all? Why not let the game generate them as needed?

Comment: It isn't producing and error. It is just not writing to the text files. I have generated the text files in my save game function, but it won't write to them. It has to do with something like where the game is stored after deployment, the location will not permit the user to write to the text files there.

Comment: Retired Ninja- I am using Install Shield free version. What I tried doing is to add the text files into the source folder of the project. Then upon deployment, just add the project folder. This all works fine and the game will deploy and run. But the text files then become read only. It will not write to those text files anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:-
1) When you deploy your text files, create a folder under the ApplicationData folder for that specific user. 
2) Deploy your text files to this folder
3) Read and write to the files in the above folder when required

The ApplicationData folder stores the application specific data of the user and is always accessible (even for non admin users)

In C++ you get the ApplicationData folder like this (pointing you to another answer on SO: [ApplicationData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899013/how-do-i-get-the-application-data-path-in-windows-using-c)

Comment: I am sorry, but I am new to this. I do not know what you mean by deploy my text files to that folder? I am using Install Shield Free edition. I have the text files included in the source folder of my game project. I then add that folder during deployment. The game will deploy and run, but the text files then become read only.

Comment: Nevermind Everyone. I found a solution. I created the directory inside the AppData folder. This is write accesible. It is now writing to the save game files. Thanks again for your replies.

Comment: Also, I think I was deploying to the wrong target folder. I was originally deploying the game into the program folder which is read only access, I changed my deployment to the appData folder, this has write access. I'm sorry. This was my first time deploying something. At least I learned some good lessons.

Comment: @AbeLincoln  Glad to see that you go it working. would be great if you can accept my answer as the solution to your question :)