# How to use environment variable in a C program

Tags: c, variables, path, environment

I need to know a way for use environment variables in the C programming language. How can I use and read them?

For example, read an environment variable or take the value of an environment variable and load it in another variable.

Comment: and now, this is among them.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html

Answer (score 48):

You can use following functions -

`char * getenv (const char *name)`-returns a string that is the value of the environment variable name.

`char * secure_getenv (const char *name)`

Read about some more functions here -http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Environment-Access.html#Environment-Access

Comment: Thanks for the useful link! But could you, please, clarify (or give a link to some kind of article clarifying) why is environment untrusted when the executable has a SUID/SGID bit set?

Comment: @Kolay.Ne With the effective uid/gid, the program might gain some additional permissions like that of the root. If the environment variables are set to some malicious value it can be harmful. Also, such programs can give users running it the same permissions and kind of like a backdoor entry.

Answer (score 18):

Use the [getenv](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/ucacbbl/getenv/) function from `stdlib.h`. That's it!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("test\n");

    const char* s = getenv("PATH");

    // If the environment variable doesn't exist, it returns NULL
    printf("PATH :%s\n", (s != NULL) ? s : "getenv returned NULL");

    printf("end test\n");
}
```

Comment: The link here is now broken. It's generally best to include more context in the answer in case an external links breaks years after it's posted.

Answer (score 12):

[getenv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/getenv):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* my_env_var = getenv("MY_ENV_VAR");

    if(my_env_var)
        printf("Var found: %s", my_env_var );
    else
        printf("Var not found.");                

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but gcc doesn't like it: "error: initializer element is not constant" gcc 7.5.0 on ubuntu18

Comment: gcc 11.2.0 ubuntu 22.04, build successfully without any error

Comment: this should include that getenv returns null if it is not found. this example doesn't show what type of falsy value it would be

Comment: @Taureon in C a value is "falsy" if it is zero. Anything else is true. So the only way for a char* to be false, is if it's zero... which is null

Comment: @MatthewPattok sounds legit to me

Answer (score 1):

On windows, you would use [GetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getenvironmentvariable).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winbase.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TCHAR buff[100] = T("");
    DWORD resultLengthInCharacters = GetEnvironmentVariable(T("USERDOMAIN"), buff, 100);

    if (resultLengthInCharacters > 0 && resultLengthInCharacters < 100) {
        _tprintf(T("USERDOMAIN: %s\n"), buff);
    } else if ( resultLengthInCharacters > 100) {
        _tprintf(T("USERDOMAIN too long to store in buffer of length 100, try again with buffer length %lu\n"), resultLengthInCharacters);
    } else {
        // Error handling incomplete, should use GetLastError(),
        // but typically:
        _tprintf(T("USERDOMAIN is empty or not set in the Environment\n"));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But if you are trying to get a standard path variable, you should use the SHGetFolderPath function with the right CSIDL variable (like from this question: [How do I get the application data path in Windows using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899013/how-do-i-get-the-application-data-path-in-windows-using-c))

Answer (score -2):

Another way could be to use the global variable `environ`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern char** environ;
void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i=0;
    while(environ[i]!=NULL){
        printf("%s\n",environ[i++]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely not the better way. You're loading variables from the global variable, so why are you including envp char pointer array in your main function arguments?

Comment: Aaaand undeclared variable`I`. Love it when people don't even check if their snippet compiles.